# Remove line between table and footnotes

Tags: tables, formatting, footnotes

I am trying to remove the line above the footnotes. I have tried following advice from similar questions here with no success. Hope someone can assist.

```
\documentclass[xcdraw, svgnames, table, a4paper, 12pt, hidelinks, twoside, colorlinks, linkcolor=black, citecolor=navy, 
urlcolor=navy, breaklinks]{report}
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}    
\restylefloat{table}    
\usepackage{geometry}    
\geometry{includehead}    
\geometry{hmargin={3.5cm,2.3cm}}    
\geometry{vmargin={1.6cm,2.5cm}}    
\geometry{headheight=15pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}    
\pagestyle{fancy}    
\fancyhead{}    
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Chapter\space \thechapter}    
\fancyfoot{}    
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\captionsetup{font={stretch=1}}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array}    
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{longtable}     
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabto}    
\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc, adjustbox}
\DefineFNsymbols*{xtfnsymbols}[math]{%
    \dagger\star \ddagger\S\P\| {\dagger
    \dagger} {\ddagger\ddagger}
}
\setfnsymbol{xtfnsymbols}

\begin{document}

The table is shown in the following page


\begin{landscape}        
\begin{table}           
\centering            
\caption{Example table}\label{tab:ext}        
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{   \begin{foo`tnotesize}            
\begin{tabular}{p{12 cm} p{6 cm}}        
\toprule        
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{What are the mechanisms of x, y and z?}} 
\\\midrule        
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Technical aspects of x} \\\midrule 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Some practices (who, when, why)} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{Change in y management}\\\midrule         
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\        
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \\        
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\        
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed  & \\        
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & \\
    \bottomrule

\end{tabular}            

\footnotetext{\textsuperscript{$\dagger$} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed.\\
\hspace*{.9cm} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed.}        
\end{footnotesize}        
}        
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems as if your footnotes are actualla tablenotes. You could use the `threeparttable` package fot this. Also keep in mind, that using `\resizebox` will lead to inconsistent font sizes. Selecting the fontsize and maybe using `tabularx` will result in more consistent tables. Lastly, `footnotesize` is not an environment that can ba used with `\begin{...}` `\end{...}` but a switch that you can use with `\footnotesize`.

Comment: I do not wish to use `threeparttable` on this instance. Thank you for the other suggestions. Is there a simple way to remove the line above the table notes?

Comment: `\let\footnoterule\relax` immediately after `\begin{table}` should do it.

Comment: @Lupino unfortunately that does not do it. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Okay, the `floatrow` package does some magic with footnotes. Add `\def\FBfootnoterule{}` after `\begin{landscape}` to locally, or before `\begin{document}` for globally deactivating the footnote rule in floats.

Comment: @Lupino would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would manipulate the footnote rule by editing LaTeX's `\footnoterule` macro. If you would suppress it completely, you just add

```
\let\footnoterule\relax
```

right before `\begin{document}`.

Since you are using the `floatrow` package this works a bit different. The package has its own mechanism to draw the footnote rule. It's macro you need to alter is called `\FBfootnoterule`. You can suppress the rule by defining this macro to be empty:

```
% choose either:
\def\FBfootnoterule{}
\let\FBfootnoterule\relax
```

Both changes can be made locally or globally. Global changes happen before `\begin{document}` (and after `\usepackage{floatrow}`). If you want that only certain environments lack the footnote rule, you can put the redefinition right after the start of that environment. In your example however, putting it within the `table` environment does not suffice due to the way the package works to place footnotes in floats. You need to use the next higher group which, in your example, is the `landscape` environment.

If you do not have a surrounding environment (e.g. a table that is not rotated), you need to create one by encapsulating your table between `\bgroup … \egroup`:

```
\bgroup
  \let\FBfootnoterule\relax%%  <-- does the magic
  \begin{table}
    %% your table content
  \end{table}%
\egroup%%                      <-- magic ends here:
```

Answer (score 1):

The `floatrow` package has an option that let's you specify the footnote rule style.

In your case, simply adding the following to preamble suppresses footnote rules for all tables:

```
\floatsetup[table]{footnoterule=none}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{footnoterule=none} % <- does the magic

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \ttabbox{\caption{Example}}{
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    lorem\footnote{amet} & ipsum\\
    dolor                & sit \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```